# Memory allocation in for loops Python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, memory-management, iterator

I can't understand where the object which is put as iterable in for loop is stored. Consider following examples:

First case:

```
ls = [2, 1, 4, 6, 7]
for i in sorted(ls):
    print(i)
```

Second case:

```
ls = [2, 1, 4, 6, 7]
reverse = sorted(ls)
for i in reverse:
    print(i)
```

I put the first case in visualiztor but while looping there is no object for sorted list, but it must be, because sorted return new object. I read that for loop under the hood uses iter method on iterable and so on, but however iterator must get information from sorted ls and because of this it must be stored somewhere, but it isn't, please help with this memory allocation case

Comment: _there is no object for sorted list_ - nope, there is object (a list), returned from calling `sorted()` function, but it's not bind/assigned to a name like in second case. You confuse the object and the name it is assigned to. There is no problem to have "anonymous" object, i.e. that is not referenced by name

Comment: `sorted()` returns a list and as such is not an iterator. `reverse` is a reference to that list and sticks around after the `for` loop is done. In either case, the `for` loop iterates over the "same" list

Comment: @buran Understand, can you please also tell if we talk about space complexity, does it mean that in the first case, we spent O(N) only for the original list and the reverse list without assignment doesn't count?

Comment: In both case, the *sorted list* is in memory, used and discarded.